# Replace value in one array with matching properties from second array

Tags: javascript

I've got two arrays:

```
arrayOne = ["green","blue","purple"]
```

and

```
arrayTwo = [
  { name: "green", id: 1 },
  { name: "red", id: 2 },
  { name: "yellow", id: 3 },
  { name: "blue", id: 8 },
]
```

I want the return array to be `[1, 8, 9]`, with "purple" being pushed as an object at the end of `arrayTwo` (with a new id).

What's the most efficient way to go about this?

Comment: Is 9 the id of purple?

Comment: Covert array into hash map where key will be name and value will be I'd, then doing your operation will take O(n)

Comment: Are the `id`s sorted on `arrayTwo`?

Comment: @Eddie Let's assume they are.

Comment: @StevenB. Purple doesn't have an id (yet), it's not present in `arrayTwo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code uses `map` to either retrieve the `id` of the element in the second array or, if that element doesn't exist, create a new one by incrementing the last `id` in that array by 1.

```js
arrayOne = ["green","blue","purple"]

arrayTwo = [
  { name: "green", id: 1 },
  { name: "red", id: 2 },
  { name: "yellow", id: 3 },
  { name: "blue", id: 8 },
]

const newArr = arrayOne.map(color => {
  const found = arrayTwo.find(el => el.name === color);
  if (found) {
    return found.id;
  }
  const newId = arrayTwo[arrayTwo.length - 1].id + 1;
  arrayTwo.push({ name: color, id: newId });
  return newId;
});

console.log(newArr);

console.log(arrayTwo);
```

**Edit:** Note that it may be brittle to assume the last item in arrayTwo contains the highest id. In that case, you can always find the max ID:

```
const newArr = arrayOne.map(color => {
  let maxId = 0;
  const found = arrayTwo.find(el => {
    if (el.id > maxId) {
      maxId = el.id;
    }
    return el.name === color 
  });
  if (found) {
    return found.id;
  }
  const newId = maxId + 1;
  arrayTwo.push({ name: color, id: newId });
  return newId;
});
```

**A thought on efficiency**

If you have any concerns about efficiency if this is going to be a large (hundreds/thousands/more) element arrays, you can consider changing `arrayTwo` to an object with color as a key:

```js
const arrayOne = ["green","blue","purple"];

const arrayTwo = [
  { name: "green", id: 1 },
  { name: "red", id: 2 },
  { name: "yellow", id: 3 },
  { name: "blue", id: 8 },
];

let maxId = 0;

// Create map
const arrayTwoMap = arrayTwo.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (el.id > maxId) maxId = el.id;
  acc[el.name] = el.id;
  return acc;
}, {});

// Find elements
const newArr = arrayOne.map(el => {
  const found = arrayTwoMap[el];
  if (found !== undefined) {
    return found;
  }
  const newId = maxId + 1;
  arrayTwoMap[el] = newId;
  return newId;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Note that it _may_ be brittle to assume the last item in `arrayTwo` contains the highest `id`. In that case, you can always find the max ID.

Comment: props for being able to figure out what the OP was expecting but also for such a detailed reply Nick

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `arrayTwo` into a `Map` (for efficiency), where the `name` is the key and the `id` is the value. Then, once you have done that, you can `.map()` `arrayOne` into an array of `id` by using each name element as a look-up key to get its associated id. If you find a `name` which is not in the `Map`, then you can add a new object, to your `arrayTwo` array, and increment the `id` counter:

```js
const arrayOne = ["green","blue","purple"];
const arrayTwo = [{ name: "green", id: 1 }, { name: "red", id: 2 }, { name: "yellow", id: 3 }, { name: "blue", id: 8 },];

let [{id:l_id}] = arrayTwo.slice(-1);
const lut = new Map(arrayTwo.map(({name, id}) => [name, id]));
const res = arrayOne.map(name => lut.get(name) || (arrayTwo.push({name, id: ++l_id}), l_id));
console.log(res);
console.log(arrayTwo);
```

If you're only concerned about the return value (and not changing array 2), you can simplify the code down:

```js
const arrayOne = ["green","blue","purple"];
const arrayTwo = [{ name: "green", id: 1 }, { name: "red", id: 2 }, { name: "yellow", id: 3 }, { name: "blue", id: 8 },];

let [{id:l_id}] = arrayTwo.slice(-1);
const lut = new Map(arrayTwo.map(({name, id}) => [name, id]));
const res = arrayOne.map(
              name => lut.get(name) || ++l_id
            );
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

this code can achieve what you want:

```js
let arrayTwo = [
  { name: "green", id: 1 },
  { name: "red", id: 2 },
  { name: "yellow", id: 3 },
  { name: "blue", id: 8 },
];

let indexes = {}, lastId = 0;

arrayTwo.forEach(({name, id}) => { 
  if(indexes[name] = id, id > lastId) lastId = id
});

function getResult(a){
  return a.map(e => indexes[e] || (arrayTwo.push({name: e, id: ++lastId}), indexes[e] = lastId))
}

// arrayOne contents
let result = getResult(["green", "blue", "purple"]);
console.log(arrayTwo, result);

// with other data
let result2 = getResult(["cyan", "blue", "purple", "azure"]);
console.log(arrayTwo, result2);
```

Hope it helps